# Question about waffle terminology

Tags: nouns

What are the little wells (dimples?) called that occur in a waffle.  These correspond to the raised areas inside of a waffle iron.

Comment: related [**The origins and usages of “waffle”**](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/205119/the-origins-and-usages-of-waffle)

Comment: When I was a kid we always called them "holes".  (And my dad fixed us waffles pretty much every Sunday.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The indentations in a waffle are called "pockets".

Comment: Citation? Or is this an opinion?

Comment: @MetaEd I don't have any single citation, but I used Google to view quite a few Belgian waffle makers, which almost uniformly refer to "deep pockets" or the like (a defining feature of Belgian waffles, incidentally the most delicious type of waffle).

Comment: I did the same sort of searching and saw it used pretty widely. That is why I accepted it.  Waffle maker manufacturers use the term.

Answer (score 7):

Apparently there is no clear concensus on what to call the indentations in waffles.  For example, a thorough article about [waffles and wafers](http://www.enotes.com/waffles-wafers-reference/waffles-wafers) with multiple references at enotes.com doesn't indicate what the dents are called.  The question has been raised three times on answers.yahoo.com, but no definitive answer has appeared.  Suggestions included *nooks* and *divots* [[1](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100923132712AAoXxTE)];  *indents, syrup holders* and *pockets* [[2](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090509191259AAzee7C)]; *honeycombs, dimples, grid indentations, dents* and *windows*
[[3](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100916200945AAlqvrs)].  Wikipedia's [waffle article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waffle) uses the word *pockets* one time, in passing.

A [Belgian waffle](http://www./reviews/main/cereals/pancake-glossary.asp) section on thenibble.com refers to them in passing as *wells*, and its [waffle](http://www.thenibble.com/reviews/main/cereals/pancake-glossary6.asp) section again uses *wells*.  A [Belgian waffle](http://www.antwerp-tourist-guide.com/belgian-waffle-maker.html) section at antwerp-tourist-guide.com uses the terms *indentations* and *pocket*.  The [waffle](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/waffle) entry at dictionary.reference.com uses *indentations* once.

A Belgian waffle [history](http://www.ehow.com/about_6556286_history-belgian-waffle.html) on ehow.com says that early waffle irons were "inspired by the shape of the alveoli (honey comb) made by bees", and thenibble's [waffle history](http://www.thenibble.com/reviews/main/cereals/waffle-history.asp) also mentions honeycomb pattern, and then comments:  "The word *gaufre*, from the Old French for waffle (*wafla*), first appears in print at this time [1200's]. *Wafla* means “a piece of honeybee hive."   From etymonline, *[waffle](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=waffle&searchmode=none)* derives ca 1744, "from Du. wafel *waffle*, from M.Du. or M.L.G. *wafel*; cognate with O.H.G. *waba*, *honeycomb*."   As meanings of *[alveolus](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/alveolus)*, plural *alveoli*, include "A small cavity or pit,"  one could also use *alveoli* as a name for the cells, wells,  pits, pockets, holes, dents, dimples, *etc* in waffles, and such usage would coordinate with the origin of the waffle pattern.