# Single word for a pattern of behaviour where you keep swapping between possibilities

Tags: single-word-requests

Some people don't have the ability to make up their mind. They keep swapping between two (or even more options). I'm not looking for a description of the type of person (like indecisive), but for a verb to describe this kind of behaviour.

Example sentence:

> Bob's {swapping behaviour} is really annoying me!

Comment: Related: "Analysis Paralysis"

Comment: "Flakiness" but it's colloquial.

Comment: Do you mean they _can't make up their mind_ between two (or more) ideas (=_indecisiveness_, IMHO), or they keep _switching_ between two (or more) options (i.e. no consistency, they choose option A on Monday, option B on Tuesday)?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

*Vacillation* would fit your criteria. For example, the *'president's vacillation over foreign policy had far reaching consequences'*.

Answer (score 8):

I would definitely say that he was [**flip-flopping**](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/flip-flopping).

> 1. Informal. a sudden or unexpected reversal, as of direction, belief, attitude, or policy.
>
> > ...
>
> 10. Informal. to make a sudden or unexpected reversal, as of direction, belief, attitude, or policy.

Example:

The opposition claimed that the president had flip-flopped on certain issues.

Answer (score 6):

Examples include:

*vacillate* and its synonyms listed on [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/vacillate)

Answer (score 5):

**indecisiveness**   [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/indecisive)

> 1. Prone to or characterized by indecision; irresolute: an indecisive manager.
> 2. Inconclusive: an indecisive contest; an indecisive battle.
> 3. Not clearly defined; indefinite:

Answer (score 2):

*Taken from [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com)*:

**to vacillate or vacillation**
The term matches your criteria perfectly, albeit it is not a common word.

**to be irresolute or irresolution**
In comparison to vacillation, this has the perk of being straightforward to understand.

**to dilly-dally**

> *(intransitive) (informal)* to loiter or vacillate.

It adds another dimension of meaning due to being informal.

I believe that all three words can be applied to your example sentence.

Answer (score 2):

Dither

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/dither

Example: Bob's dithering is really annoying me!

Answer (score 2):

"Waffling", in keeping with the annoyed tone.

Comment: Although "waffle" would usually be taken to mean something else in British English : see https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/205119/the-origins-and-usages-of-waffle for more discussion

Answer (score 1):

I've also heard "waver" or "wavering": Bob's *wavering* is really annoying me!

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use "**oscillation**" :

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/oscillate?q=oscillation

> **oscillate**
> verb [ I ] UK ​  /ˈɒs.ɪ.leɪt/ US ​  /ˈɑː.səl.eɪt/
>
> to move repeatedly from one position to another:
> "*The needle on the dial oscillated between full and empty*  "
>
> [formal] If you oscillate between feelings or opinions, you change repeatedly from one to the other:
> "*My emotions oscillate between desperation and hope.*"
>
> (...)

Answer (score -2):

alternating between two poles or options